# Problem after expanding boot partition

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, partition, storage

I needed extra space on my `/boot` partition so I took  the SD card, inserted it into my PC and expanded/moved the partitions using GParted (this to my surprise took over 4 hours to complete).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       25660524 1777960  22815436   8% /
devtmpfs          470176       0    470176   0% /dev
tmpfs             474784       0    474784   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             474784    6360    468424   2% /run
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             474784       0    474784   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1     41976   29357     12619  70% /boot          # 41 MB

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 28.9G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 24.9G  0 part /
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0    4G  0 part /boot                     # 4 GB
```

As you can see `lsblk` shows the boot partition to be 4 GB, but  `df` reports it's 41 MB (that was its size before I expanded it). Also writing files larger than the free space `df` shows doesn't work.

How do fix my `/boot (mmcblk0p1)` partition so it's correctly expanded to 4 GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the partition has the expected size, but not the file system on it. Perhaps `gparted` has failed that last part and you have not noticed it.

First of all, you should run [fsck.vfat](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck.vfat) on this partition, because it seems they were a problem the first time you tried.

Then I would recommend to either retry with `gparted` or using [`fatresize`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/fatresize.1.html).

It should take a much shorter time since the data from the second partition will not be moved this time.